# Extract file from .apk?

Tags: java, android

in my android app I'm using an own java library that extracts a `.db`-file from jar. In Java desktop it works well, but when I try to do it on android, the inputstream blocks forever. The copy method looks like this:

```
InputStream in = classloader.getResourceAsStream(...);
OutputStream out = new FileOutputStream(new File(...));
try {
  while ((read = in.read()) != -1) {
    out.write(read);
  }
} finally {
  try {
    in.close();
  } catch (final Exception e) {
    LOGGER.debug("Error", e);
  }

  try {
    out.close();
  } catch (final Exception e) {
    LOGGER.debug("Error", e);
  }
}
```

I want to copy this file to the external files dir and `android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE` is granted.

Is there a way to access the file in `/data/app/...apk`? If not, how can I detect that it can not be accessed without blocking forever?

Comment: Is this about shipping your app with a filled database?

Comment: Yes, the app should contain a filled database. On first start, the database should be extracted and updated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should put the database-file in the `/assets`-folder and copy it to the `/databases`-folder on first run. A tutorial on this can be found [here](http://www.reigndesign.com/blog/using-your-own-sqlite-database-in-android-applications/).

However, if you only want to create the tables and some sample-entry's, you might want to use the [`onCreate()`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/database/sqlite/SQLiteOpenHelper.html#onCreate%28android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase%29)-method from the [`SQLiteOpenHelper`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/database/sqlite/SQLiteOpenHelper.html) to do so.

Comment: I will try that. But I want to copy the file to the external storage.

Comment: You can do that, too (if you have the "Write External Storage"-permission).

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you should store your data in the raw folder, you access it then :)

http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/resources/index.html

Answer (score 0):

Answering to the question : we can  only extract the class files from the apk that we have got, we will not get the layout/xml files or any other files.

There are ways by which we can extract the class files from the apk.